# Why does the search field get focus after selecting a row in my tableview?

Tags: ios, first-responder

I have a view with a search field and below it a table view.
When I select a cell in my table view, it automatically shows the keyboard and focuses the cursor on the search field.

I don't want the keyboard to show if the user selects a tableview cell. One solution is to make the keyboard disappear on cell selection, but if the keyboard was already there I should not dismiss it. I could also track if the keyboard was already there, but I feel it starts to be a lot of hacks

How should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: is there any kind of relation between the cells and the textView?

Comment: @BashirSidani there is a big view that has a header (with searchbar) and the tableview below

Comment: you have an action triggered when you click a cell?

Comment: if yes, in the first line of the method, get the UITextView that is the first responder. and on the last linei n the method, let it become first responder again. that way you dont loose anything

Comment: how do you get the first responder ? loop through all subviews?

Comment: yes, here is a code: for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.isFirstResponder) {
        [self doSomethingCleverWithView:view];
    }
}